# How can I configure logs as data source from remote unix server in splunk?

Tags: unix

How can I configure splunk with log files residing on remote unix servers?

Normally I log into putty to a linux server, from there I ssh into another company server and I navigate through directories and perform my operations mainly as `cat`, `zcat` etc., with grep filters. Ex:

1. login to example_server with putty
2. ssh to ssh_server
3. cd to req dir
4. perform cat etc.,

ssh_server will not directly allow to be logged in from putty, I have to first login to example_server and then to ssh_server.

How can I configure these log files to be used by splunk to search for a string, similarly to how I use grep. I've installed splunk on my laptop, and by clicking `add data > files` and `dir > add new` it shows full path to the data field, what path should I fill it with?

Comment: I would take this question to serverfault or superuser (or rather, per-use the Splunk documentation)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to install the Splunk Universal Forwarder (UF) on the remote Linux system.  The UF is free and requires no license.

For more info - http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Usingforwardingagents

Answer (score 0):

In case it is not possible to install any new binary on the monitored server (like in my case) you should evaluate other options:

- using the get log data from script option in splunk and creating a script looking like :
    ssh user@10.10.10.10 cat /var/logs/logfile.log
    warning: it will blow your index if you have a short polling interval and big logs, as    each log event is registered every time you poll the file.
- using a cron job runnig rsync to mirror the logs on the splunk server localy:
    the job would look like this 
    /usr/bin/rsync -az  user@10.10.10.10:/var/logs/ /var/remoteLogs/
    In this case every added line will only generate a single log event i splunk

for both solutions installed SSH keys are mandatory